# How to get Top 10% from a column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset with employee details, revenue generation, and salary.
I want to find the sum of revenue generated by the employees who are getting Top 10% of salary.

My question is How to Filter top 10% values in a specific column then return the sum or count of another column.

```
SELECT sum(RVNU_YEAR_A) WHERE(
SELECT
TOP 10 PERCENT 
SLRY_YEAR_A
FROM ROYAL_BANK_AUS.CUST_BASE
ORDER BY RVNU_YEAR_A)
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you got us some data for testing. So far I can understand the problem, I'd suggest you to find "employees who are getting Top 10% of salary." first (in a "subquery") and then calculate the revenue

The "order by" is not allowed within a sub-query so you have to use "with" clause (aka CTE - common table expression)

```
with top10pct as (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT *
                    FROM ROYAL_BANK_AUS.CUST_BASE
                   ORDER BY SLRY_YEAR_A)
     
select sum(RVNU_YEAR_A)
  from top10pct;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I am having some problem with the code syntax

It's showing ERROR 1064. You have an error with syntax

For some reason Top 10 is not working in my SQL.

Comment: Hi @Akashdeep - "order by" is not allowed in subqueries. I've updated my answer. Try this one please

Answer (score 0):

The query below returns the top 10% of `SLRY_YEAR_A` and then calculates the sum of the `RVNU_YEAR_A` values.

```
SELECT SUM(RVNU_YEAR_A) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT SLRY_YEAR_A,RVNU_YEAR_A
FROM ROYAL_BANK_AUS.CUST_BASE
ORDER BY RVNU_YEAR_A)
```